# Inconsistent behavior in powershell with null parameters

Tags: powershell, parameters, null

I need to write a function in powershell that tells apart a 'parameter not being passed' from one passed with string empty (or any other string)

I wrote it like this:

```
function Set-X {
    param(
    [AllowNull()][string]$MyParam = [System.Management.Automation.Language.NullString]::Value
    )

    if ($null -ne $MyParam) { write-host 'oops' }
    else { write-host 'ok' }
}
```

If I call Set-X without parameters from ISE, it works as I expect and prints 'ok'.

But if I do that from the normal console, it prints 'oops'.

What is going on? What is the proper way to do it?

Comment: Have you tried looking at `[string]::IsNullOrEmpty()`? That will allow you to check for a null or empty string. There is also `[string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace()`

Comment: IsNullOrEmpty() does not tell apart null from empty.

Comment: What do you want to dispay if i type in : Set-X  -MyParam "hey" ; Set-X  -MyParam ; Set-X

Comment: I believe the problem is that you are casting your parameter to a `[string]`. As `[string]$null -eq ''` returns `True` vs `$null -eq ''` returns `False`

Comment: @ArcSet, I expect: Set-X -MyParam "hey" -> should display 'oops'; Set-X -> should display 'ok'; Set-X -MyParam -> I didn't think about this case, but since $MyParam is not [switch], I think it should result in some type of error in the function call

Comment: As BenH suggested, if I remove the [string] cast it works consistently across ISE and console, as long as I also change the default value to $null => [AllowNull()]$MyParam = $null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Mathias and BenH have written, the culprit is casting $null to the [string] type, which results in an empty string:

```
 [string]$null -eq '' #This is True
```

But for the sample code in Mathias answer to work correctly we also have to replace

```
[System.Management.Automation.Language.NullString]::Value
```

with $null

```
function Set-X {
    param(
    [AllowNull()]$MyParam = $null
    )

    if ($null -ne $MyParam) { write-host 'oops' }
    else { write-host 'ok' }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Allowing the user to pass in a parameter argument value of `$null` does not change the fact that powershell will attempt to convert it to a `[string]`.

Converting a `$null` value in powershell to a string results in an empty string:

```
$str = [string]$null
$null -eq $str # False
'' -eq $str    # True
```

*(same goes for `$null -as [string]` and `"$null"`)*

Remove the type constraint on the `MyParam` parameter if you not only want to *allow* `$null` but also *accept* `$null` as a parameter value:

```
function Set-X {
    param(
    [AllowNull()]$MyParam = [System.Management.Automation.Language.NullString]::Value
    )

    if ($null -ne $MyParam) { write-host 'oops' }
    else { write-host 'ok' }
}
```

Comment: This is the correct answer, as also pointed out by BenH in his comment. But you also have to change the default assignment to simply $null, instead of [System.Management.Automation.Language.NullString]::Value